# Calculate the user account balance from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have two tables:

1 Payment table

```
PID  Amount  IsOk
=======================
10   50     true
10   92     false
14   73     true
14   22     true
15   10     true
```

2 Withdraws table

```
PID  Amount  IsOk
=======================
10   23     true
14   98     false
14   15     true
```

I want `subtract(sum of withdraws amounts) and (sum of withdraws amounts) where IsOk=true` for any PID like this

```
PID  Balance  
=======================
10   27   //50-23
14   80   //73+22-15
15   10   //10
```

Comment: `14   95   //73+22` why ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What exactly is the question you want us to answer?

Comment: [Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219979/serg)  sry i edited.

Comment: Apply  `GROUP BY` to a `UNION ALL` of  first table as is and the second table negating `Amount` . Sure provide a proper `WHERE` to exclude `false` marks,

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select pid, sum(amount) balance balance
from (
    select pid, amount from payment where isOk = 'true'
    union all
    seect pid, -amount from withdraws where isOk = 'true'
) t
group by pid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
SELECT T.PID, SUM(T.Amount) - SUM(DISTINCT ISNULL(TT.Amount, 0))
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (10,   50,     1),
    (10,   92,     0),
    (14,   73,     1),
    (14,   22,     1),
    (15,   10,     1)
) T(PID,  Amount,  IsOk)
LEFT JOIN
(
    VALUES
    (10,   23, 1),
    (14,   98, 0),
    (14,   15, 1)
) TT(PID, Amount, IsOk)
ON T.PID = TT.PID AND TT.IsOk = 1
WHERE  T.IsOk = 1 
GROUP BY T.PID;
```

Which will returns:

```
+-----+------------------+
| PID | (No column name) |
+-----+------------------+
|  10 |               27 |
|  14 |               80 |
|  15 |               10 |
+-----+------------------+
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3550062caafb71ee1636c36fe460508)